# I'm not getting the elapsed time in seconds

Tags: c++

I need to know the elapsed time of my program in seconds. Just the elapsed time, I'm not doing anything in between, so I DON'T need the time between two events, all I want to do is already in the code.

```
clock_t begin = clock();
float timeElapsed = (float)begin/(CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
cout << timeElapsed << endl;
```

The problem is, the "time" is being printed, but it is not in seconds. I even compared it with a chronometer, and it definitely is not in seconds. When something like "1.27818" appears on the screen, I expect it to be 1.27818 seconds, but it is clearly not. It takes too much time to get to 1 and this time is definitely not one second. What's going on? Wasn't "(float)begin/(CLOCKS_PER_SEC)" supposed to return in seconds?

UPDATE
I did this:

```
clock_t begin = clock();
float timeElapsed = (float)(clock() - begin)/(CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
cout << timeElapsed << endl;
```

But I'm getting values like these:

```
0
1e-06
1e-06
0
1e-06
1e-06
2e-06
1e-06
```

Comment: Use [std::chrono](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono).

Comment: elapsed time is the difference between two clock() calls.

Comment: I don't think that clock() is 0 at the start of your program.

Comment: On linux, you can prefix the compilation/execution with the `time` command. Eg `time x.cpp`/`time ./a.out`

Comment: It is operating system specific, unless you only use `std::chrono` or `<time.h>` from C. On Linux read [time(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/time.7.html); you have different sort of times, real time, elapsed time, monotonic time,  thread cpu time, process cpu time. BTW, for small amount of time the *hardware* might not be precise enough

Comment: Well if you are not doing anything between the calls I expect the result to be similar to what you get. I mean you can only expect  0 or 1 clock tick to have elapsed between calls to clock() because the resolution of clock() is typically not that high.

Comment: ***Just the elapsed time, I'm not doing anything in between, so I DON'T need the time between two events*** This part does not make a lot of sense to me. There will be no elapsed time if you do not do anything between.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at this example:

```
int main ()
{
  clock_t t;
  int f;
  t = clock();
  printf ("Calculating...\n");
  f = call_some_function();
  printf ("Result: %d\n",f);
  t = clock() - t;
  printf ("It took me %d clicks (%f seconds).\n",t,((float)t)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
  return 0;
}
```

One thing to note is you might want to do subtraction of clock() - begin after the operation, to get the time elapsed of the operation.

Comment: I did this but I'm getting values like "1e-06, 2e-06, 3e-06, 2e-06, 0". In this sequence, which doesn't make sense

Comment: That is in scientific notation. 1e-06 means 1x10^-6 etc. This is expected since you are calling clock() and clock()-begin in just consecutive lines

Answer (score 0):

The values you got are in [scientific notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation), if you want plain form you should use [`std::fixed`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/fixed) stream manipulator. For example:

```
std::cout << std::fixed << data;
```

Also [documents](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/clock) about `std::clock()` say:

> **Only the difference between two values returned by different calls to std::clock is meaningful, as the beginning of the std::clock era does not have to coincide with the start of the program. std::clock time may advance faster or slower than the wall clock**, depending on the execution resources given to the program by the operating system. For example, if the CPU is shared by other processes, std::clock time may advance slower than wall clock. On the other hand, if the current process is multithreaded and more than one execution core is available, std::clock time may advance faster than wall clock.

Also there's a [good example](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/clock#Example) at the bottom of that page.

Comment: But they're also out of order... I tried using fixed, but then I got: "..., 0.000000
0.000000, 0.000001, 0.000001, 0.000002, ...". It seems like it is restarting all the time

Comment: I would expect your result. You need to do something between the calls to clock().

Comment: @jaryl What `clock()` returns is _approximately_ the time processor has given to your program. That's not wall clock. If processor preempts your process that `clock()` stops until scheduler dispatches your process to the processor again.

Answer (score 0):

You need a starting time and an ending time. Subtract them and then divide it by CLOCKS_PER_SEC.

Do this:

```
clock_t begin = clock();
/* 

Do your process

*/
clock_t end = clock();
float timeElapsed = (float)(end-begin)/(CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
cout << timeElapsed << endl;
```

You get the answer in ticks, in scientific notations. Note that 1 second= 10^6 ticks. You need to multiply your answer by 1 million to get answer in seconds.